# Add FK field in table when there are already records on that table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Let say FB didnt have gender_id before in their users table, and suddenly they decided to add it as required field.

What would happen if they add this field as fk in the same table users, when all other records doesn't have a value of gender_id. in fact mysql doesnt let you do that until u have an gender_id value to add to other records too.

Of course they cannot delete all users to do this, my question is, what is the best solution for this case?

1.I was thinking add this field in a new table and reference the user_id with gender_id, so for the incoming users to necessarily have gender_id.

2.Add new record to genders like 0=male,1=female,2=unsigned so by default add unsigned value (2) for all other users

What is you opinion?

Comment: I think "undesignated" might be what you mean. You really don't need to deal with defaults though. You can add the column and set the value explicitly unless you want to continue using the default going forward.

Comment: @shawnt00, what do you mean by undesignated term?

Do you have more pragmatic example?

Comment: You used the word "unsigned". My initial thought was that you intended to say "undesignated" but now I think you may have meant "unassigned". It's only a comment regarding English.

Comment: Yes I meant "unassigned" sorry, so do u say to leave it unassigned, with a default value?

Comment: Ok, well there is such a thing as "gender re-assignment" so you may think about just going with something generic like "not saved" (for PC considerations.) Otherwise I do agree that you probably need to flag them with a third value. Whether you actually need a default depends on how you plan to insert new rows in the future. I suspect you really don't need that part.

Comment: @shawnt00 How about if I could just leave it as nullable? would it be the same thing?

Comment: I think I misread how you intended to use the default. I believe you want to run `alter table add...default(2)` to create the new column. Yes, you can certainly use a default in order to make it non-nullable. I might suggest removing the default after you're done or alternately adding it as nullable, updating, and the changing it to non-null.

Comment: @shawnt00 I can accept your comment as an adecuate answer

Comment: Thanks. Sam's answer was just as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s exactly what I would do. Add the FK field with a default of 0, I like to use 0 as the unknown case, then maybe 1=male, 2=female. I would NOT allow NULL in the field, and always default it to 0 if no value provided.